# How to prevent capturing API link?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

**How to prevent by capturing API link.**

I use to get URL from firebase then i pass the URL to Volley to parse JSON data.
By using rooted phone and some packet capture tools available on PlayStore. URL is easily captured.
And if i put root check condition it will not work because now using magisk we can hide root easily.

what is the best way to prevent packet capturing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use https and certificate pinning:
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl

You can't hide the server address though.

Comment: how can i pass InputStream to volley as an url?